# phonegap 2.5.0 jqtouch fail inizialize

Tags: cordova, initialization, jqtouch

Seems that Phonegap 2.5.0 broke something with jQTouch.
If in code we try to initialize jQt (as in previously Phonegap releases) with:

```
var jQT = new $.jQTouch({}=;

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);

// PhoneGap is ready
function onDeviceReady() {
  dosomething();
}
```

Then it will not work, the app hung on splashscreen. Btw if the jQTouch initialize it's done inside "onDeviceReady" then the app start but the "jQT" object it's not seen globally on code, it will need to be inizialized on every functions?

Please help,
Thanks Roob

Comment: Anyone on this? I've saw also a comment on Phonegap blog about this problem http://shazronatadobe.wordpress.com/2013/03/04/whats-new-in-cordova-ios-2-5-0/

Comment: As Shazron suggested i've filed a bug on https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2904

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work by using the structure that comes by default in the index.js file from the phonegap installation for ios like this:

```
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },

    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },

    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },

    receivedEvent: function() {

        //jQTouch init here
        var jQT = new $.jQTouch({
            useFastTouch : true,
            touchSelector : 'a, .btn, .touch'
        });

        //Put the rest of your app in here


    }
};
```

Hope this helps! :)

*dont forget to initialize your app - app.initialize();

Comment: Hi Jotav! Thanks a lot i will test and report!

Comment: Hi Jotav, i've tried it but it's similar to put jQT initialization inside the "onDeviceReady" event.
The run but when the jQT object is called example: jQT.goTo(... i get the "can't find variable: jQT".

Comment: Hi oukuden! I migrated an app with jQT from phonegap 2.3 to 2.6, at first i had the problem that you comment. But then i changed my init with the method i posted above and all my jQT.goTo() references work fine. I hope you can get it running soon.

Comment: Hi Jotav, thanks in the example your comment says "//put the rest of your code here" so ALL the code must be referenced inside the receivedEnvent section? I will investigate more, can You gently extend the example with some calls to jQT object? Thanks a Lot!

Comment: Hi Jotova! got it working with a more simpler approach (it was simple but not tried yet...). First i've initialized the jQT variable OUTSIDE the ondeviceready function with <code>var jQT = null;</code> then INSIDE the ondeviceready function i have the <code>jQT = new new $.jQTouch({});</code> It's working ok! I've only lost the back auto-button i need to specify jQT.GoBack() but it's not a problem Thanks a Lot! Ciao Rob

Comment: Hi oukuden, just read your lasts comments. I give you a recommendation, get rid of jQTouch. I got it out of my app, made custom transitions and used fastclick js and my app feels much more fast with a much better user expiriance overall. And jQTouchs navigation system feels kinda old now in 2013.

Comment: Hi Jotav, yes thanks for the suggestion, custom css transition or js? Btw i've looked also at AppFramework from Intel that seems to be a very good alternative for UI Thanks Ciao Rob